# TypeError when using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Recently I'm working on a calculator project and I've designed the layout and when I'm trying to add click functions to the operator buttons, it turns out a TypeError: operator[i] is undefined. I'm pretty sure it's the addEventListner causing this issue as I tried to console.log the innerHTML of the operator nodes before and after it and I'm only having trouble inside the function. Here is my code:

My JavaScript code is still in process so please don't mind it's not working like other calculators do (eg. the buttons are only allowed to be pressed once lol :)  )

```js
var number = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=number]"),
  operator = document.querySelectorAll("[class|=o]"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
  equal = document.getElementById("equal"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  isEqualed = false;

for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.innerHTML = number[i].innerHTML;
  })
}
for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  console.log(operator[i]);
  operator[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(operator[i]);
    input.innerHTML = operator[i].innerHTML;
  }, true)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input input input input" "o-addition o-subtraction o-multiplication o-division" "number7 number8 number9 equal" "number4 number5 number6 equal" "number1 number2 number3 equal" "number0 numberdot clear equal";
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: input;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15%;
}

[class|=o],
[class^=number],
#clear {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[class |=o]:hover,
[class^=number]:hover,
#equal:hover,
#clear:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: outset 0 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.o-addition {
  grid-area: o-addition;
}

.o-subtraction {
  grid-area: o-subtraction;
}

.o-multiplication {
  grid-area: o-multiplication;
}

.o-division {
  grid-area: o-division;
}

.number1 {
  grid-area: number1;
}

.number2 {
  grid-area: number2;
}

.number3 {
  grid-area: number3;
}

.number4 {
  grid-area: number4;
}

.number5 {
  grid-area: number5;
}

.number6 {
  grid-area: number6;
}

.number7 {
  grid-area: number7;
}

.number8 {
  grid-area: number8;
}

.number9 {
  grid-area: number9;
}

.number0 {
  grid-area: number0;
}

.numberdot {
  grid-area: numberdot;
}

#clear {
  grid-area: clear;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 200% 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="calculator">
  <meta name="description" content="calcultor">
  <meta name="author" content="Nick Hui">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devic-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="input"></div>
    <div class="o-addition">+</div>
    <div class="o-subtraction">-</div>
    <div class="o-multiplication">*</div>
    <div class="o-division">/</div>
    <div class="number1">1</div>
    <div class="number2">2</div>
    <div class="number3">3</div>
    <div class="number4">4</div>
    <div class="number5">5</div>
    <div class="number6">6</div>
    <div class="number7">7</div>
    <div class="number8">8</div>
    <div class="number9">9</div>
    <div class="number0">0</div>
    <div class="numberdot">.</div>
    <div id="clear">C</div>
    <div id="equal">=</div>
  </div>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In YOUR event listener you needed `this` or a closure over the number. Since a closure is unnecessary if you use this or delegate like I suggest, we'll keep that for a future use

```
number[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  input.textContent = this.textContent;
})
```

If you delegate it will work better and simpler (DRY)

You still need to do the calculation but the event listeners work

```js
var number = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=number]"),
  operator = document.querySelectorAll("[class|=o]"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
  equal = document.getElementById("equal"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  isEqualed = false;

document.getElementById("calculator").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("number")) {
    input.textContent += tgt.textContent;
  }
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("o")) {
    input.textContent += tgt.textContent; 
    // and do something
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input input input input" "o-addition o-subtraction o-multiplication o-division" "number7 number8 number9 equal" "number4 number5 number6 equal" "number1 number2 number3 equal" "number0 numberdot clear equal";
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: input;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15%;
}

[class|=o],
[class^=number],
#clear {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[class |=o]:hover,
[class^=number]:hover,
#equal:hover,
#clear:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: outset 0 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.o-addition {
  grid-area: o-addition;
}

.o-subtraction {
  grid-area: o-subtraction;
}

.o-multiplication {
  grid-area: o-multiplication;
}

.o-division {
  grid-area: o-division;
}

.number1 {
  grid-area: number1;
}

.number2 {
  grid-area: number2;
}

.number3 {
  grid-area: number3;
}

.number4 {
  grid-area: number4;
}

.number5 {
  grid-area: number5;
}

.number6 {
  grid-area: number6;
}

.number7 {
  grid-area: number7;
}

.number8 {
  grid-area: number8;
}

.number9 {
  grid-area: number9;
}

.number0 {
  grid-area: number0;
}

.numberdot {
  grid-area: numberdot;
}

#clear {
  grid-area: clear;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 200% 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="input"></div>
    <div class="o" id="addition">+</div>
    <div class="o" id="subtraction">-</div>
    <div class="o" id="multiplication">*</div>
    <div class="o" id="division">/</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="number">6</div>
    <div class="number">7</div>
    <div class="number">8</div>
    <div class="number">9</div>
    <div class="number">0</div>
    <div class="number">.</div>
    <div id="clear">C</div>
    <div id="equal">=</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hi I understand your code and it definitely works :) But I want to know why my code doesn't work and how to fix it. Otherwise I will face the same problem again and don't know how to fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: You need `this.textContent` instead of your array access in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You're facing a scoping issue, if you click the numbers you will see that the only number that works is the first you press after that if you try to press another button you will see that not works.

## Why this happens?

The problem here is that the value of each iteration doesn't remains constant within the scope of your event listener callback function.

[Reference](https://gomakethings.com/why-you-shouldnt-attach-event-listeners-in-a-for-loop-with-vanilla-javascript/)

## Solution 1

You can save the value to reference it.

```js
var number = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=number]"),
  operator = document.querySelectorAll("[class|=o]"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
  equal = document.getElementById("equal"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  isEqualed = false;

for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  const currentNumber = number[i];
  currentNumber.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.innerHTML = currentNumber.innerHTML;
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  const currentOperator = operator[i];
  currentOperator.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() {
      input.innerHTML = currentOperator.innerHTML;
    },
    true
  );
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input input input input" "o-addition o-subtraction o-multiplication o-division" "number7 number8 number9 equal" "number4 number5 number6 equal" "number1 number2 number3 equal" "number0 numberdot clear equal";
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: input;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15%;
}

[class|="o"],
[class^="number"],
#clear {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[class|="o"]:hover,
[class^="number"]:hover,
#equal:hover,
#clear:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: outset 0 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.o-addition {
  grid-area: o-addition;
}

.o-subtraction {
  grid-area: o-subtraction;
}

.o-multiplication {
  grid-area: o-multiplication;
}

.o-division {
  grid-area: o-division;
}

.number1 {
  grid-area: number1;
}

.number2 {
  grid-area: number2;
}

.number3 {
  grid-area: number3;
}

.number4 {
  grid-area: number4;
}

.number5 {
  grid-area: number5;
}

.number6 {
  grid-area: number6;
}

.number7 {
  grid-area: number7;
}

.number8 {
  grid-area: number8;
}

.number9 {
  grid-area: number9;
}

.number0 {
  grid-area: number0;
}

.numberdot {
  grid-area: numberdot;
}

#clear {
  grid-area: clear;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 200% 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="calculator" />
  <meta name="description" content="calcultor" />
  <meta name="author" content="Nick Hui" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devic-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="input"></div>
    <div class="o-addition">+</div>
    <div class="o-subtraction">-</div>
    <div class="o-multiplication">*</div>
    <div class="o-division">/</div>
    <div class="number1">1</div>
    <div class="number2">2</div>
    <div class="number3">3</div>
    <div class="number4">4</div>
    <div class="number5">5</div>
    <div class="number6">6</div>
    <div class="number7">7</div>
    <div class="number8">8</div>
    <div class="number9">9</div>
    <div class="number0">0</div>
    <div class="numberdot">.</div>
    <div id="clear">C</div>
    <div id="equal">=</div>
  </div>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

## Solution 2

Using ***[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)***

```js
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=number]"),
  operators = document.querySelectorAll("[class|=o]"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
  equal = document.getElementById("equal"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  isEqualed = false;

numbers.forEach(function (number) {
  number.addEventListener("click", function () {
    input.innerHTML = number.innerHTML;
  });
});

operators.forEach(function (operator) {
  operator.addEventListener("click", function () {
    input.innerHTML = operator.innerHTML;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input input input input" "o-addition o-subtraction o-multiplication o-division" "number7 number8 number9 equal" "number4 number5 number6 equal" "number1 number2 number3 equal" "number0 numberdot clear equal";
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: input;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15%;
}

[class|="o"],
[class^="number"],
#clear {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[class|="o"]:hover,
[class^="number"]:hover,
#equal:hover,
#clear:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: outset 0 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.o-addition {
  grid-area: o-addition;
}

.o-subtraction {
  grid-area: o-subtraction;
}

.o-multiplication {
  grid-area: o-multiplication;
}

.o-division {
  grid-area: o-division;
}

.number1 {
  grid-area: number1;
}

.number2 {
  grid-area: number2;
}

.number3 {
  grid-area: number3;
}

.number4 {
  grid-area: number4;
}

.number5 {
  grid-area: number5;
}

.number6 {
  grid-area: number6;
}

.number7 {
  grid-area: number7;
}

.number8 {
  grid-area: number8;
}

.number9 {
  grid-area: number9;
}

.number0 {
  grid-area: number0;
}

.numberdot {
  grid-area: numberdot;
}

#clear {
  grid-area: clear;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 200% 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="calculator" />
    <meta name="description" content="calcultor" />
    <meta name="author" content="Nick Hui" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devic-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="calculator">
      <div id="input"></div>
      <div class="o-addition">+</div>
      <div class="o-subtraction">-</div>
      <div class="o-multiplication">*</div>
      <div class="o-division">/</div>
      <div class="number1">1</div>
      <div class="number2">2</div>
      <div class="number3">3</div>
      <div class="number4">4</div>
      <div class="number5">5</div>
      <div class="number6">6</div>
      <div class="number7">7</div>
      <div class="number8">8</div>
      <div class="number9">9</div>
      <div class="number0">0</div>
      <div class="numberdot">.</div>
      <div id="clear">C</div>
      <div id="equal">=</div>
    </div>
    <script src="calculator.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just use `this` or delegate like I did instead of wasting a closure on something trivial

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! So I understand now that's all the closure problem, an outer function can pass variables to inner functions but an inner function cannot pass variables to outer functions. So the addEventListener will delete the i variable when the first iteration is finished and the for loop cannot receive an i variable and therefore ends the loop. Am I right?

Comment: The problem is with the traditional for loop, when you pass the callback to the addEventListener in that moment you are saving an function into the browser API, it means that when the event loop is ready to execute the callback function from the event queue the variable i doesn't exist anymore and you get an error because you lost the context with the traditional for then you can save the context as the solution 1, or you can use the forEachLoop that it is attaching the context to the addEventListener or like mplunjan said is a good way too just referencing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a “closures in loops problem” which can easily be solved by using `let` instead of `var`.

```js
/*
  Using const because of personal preference. You can use var or let here also
*/
const number = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=number]"),
  operator = document.querySelectorAll("[class|=o]"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
  equal = document.getElementById("equal"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  isEqualed = false;

/*
  Using let for i, so each iteration gets its own variable
*/
for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.innerHTML = number[i].innerHTML;
  })
}

/*
  Using let for i, so each iteration gets its own variable
*/
for (let i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  operator[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.innerHTML = operator[i].innerHTML;
  }, true)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input input input input" "o-addition o-subtraction o-multiplication o-division" "number7 number8 number9 equal" "number4 number5 number6 equal" "number1 number2 number3 equal" "number0 numberdot clear equal";
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: input;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15%;
}

[class|=o],
[class^=number],
#clear {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[class |=o]:hover,
[class^=number]:hover,
#equal:hover,
#clear:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: outset 0 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.o-addition {
  grid-area: o-addition;
}

.o-subtraction {
  grid-area: o-subtraction;
}

.o-multiplication {
  grid-area: o-multiplication;
}

.o-division {
  grid-area: o-division;
}

.number1 {
  grid-area: number1;
}

.number2 {
  grid-area: number2;
}

.number3 {
  grid-area: number3;
}

.number4 {
  grid-area: number4;
}

.number5 {
  grid-area: number5;
}

.number6 {
  grid-area: number6;
}

.number7 {
  grid-area: number7;
}

.number8 {
  grid-area: number8;
}

.number9 {
  grid-area: number9;
}

.number0 {
  grid-area: number0;
}

.numberdot {
  grid-area: numberdot;
}

#clear {
  grid-area: clear;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 200% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="input"></div>
  <div class="o-addition">+</div>
  <div class="o-subtraction">-</div>
  <div class="o-multiplication">*</div>
  <div class="o-division">/</div>
  <div class="number1">1</div>
  <div class="number2">2</div>
  <div class="number3">3</div>
  <div class="number4">4</div>
  <div class="number5">5</div>
  <div class="number6">6</div>
  <div class="number7">7</div>
  <div class="number8">8</div>
  <div class="number9">9</div>
  <div class="number0">0</div>
  <div class="numberdot">.</div>
  <div id="clear">C</div>
  <div id="equal">=</div>
</div>
```

Comment: However delegation is much more elegant